# img source in a component vue js

Tags: image, vue.js, vue-component

i am new to vue js and i have a problem with my img in the component

here is my code :

component

```
<template>
  <div class="features">
    <div class="features_text">
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <h3>{{text}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="features_img">
      <img src="{{src}}" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: `Features`,
  props: {
    title: String,
    text: String,
    src: String
  }
}
```

page:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <Features title="a title" text="a text" src="../assets/image.png">
    </div>
<template>
```

but no image is displaying

how can i make that ?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: nothing is displayed

Comment: No error in the console? What do you see in the DOM?

Comment: @kissu no error, no images

Comment: @Swampy Can you first check if this image is rendering in parent component or not ? If not then it might be a path issue or image accessing issue

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, make sure you change your binding inside the `Features` component to:

```
<img :src="src" alt="" />
```

If that doesn't help, try importing the image rather than having a relative path. This way, if your path is wrong you might get an error message.

```
import myImageSource from 'path/to/image.png'
```

Answer (score -1):

Append binding to the src attribute

```
<img :src="{{src}}" alt="">
```

[Vue docs on v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind)

Comment: Please remove the double curly braces. Vue binding should look like this: `<img :src="src" />`

Comment: This is a Vue question, not React. No double brackets needed here.

Comment: @Danielola it don't work

Comment: Thanks @Dr4jw3r.

Would you rather check the console for possible hints to fix this error, @ Swampy?